# Enable to import flask in python

Tags: python, reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have react app which communicates with flask API and display data. I had both of these projects in separate folders and everything worked fine.

Then I wanted to containerize Flask + React app with docker-compose for practice and then I created a folder in which I have my middleware(flask) and frontend(react) folders. Then I created a virtual environment and installed flask. Now when I import flask inside python file I get an error.

I do not understand why simply adding the folder inside another folder would affect my project. You can see the project structure and error in the picture below.

Dockerfile react app

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Dockerfile flask api

```
FROM python:3.7.2

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add requirements (to leverage Docker cache)
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD python app.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    middleware:
        build: ./middleware
        expose:
            - 5000
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        volumes:
            - ./middleware:/usr/src/app
        environment:
            - FLASK_ENV=development
            - FLASK_APP=app.py
            - FLASK_DEBUG=1
    frontend:
        build: ./frontend
        expose:
            - 3000
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        volumes:
            - ./frontend/src:/usr/src/app/src
            - ./frontend/public:/usr/src/app/public
        links:
            - "middleware:middleware"
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: Provide your `docker-compose` file, any `dockerfile`, exact error you are getting.

Comment: You should probably change the python path in your settings.

Comment: @zmbq wow! it worked.

Comment: I'll turn this into an answer so others can find it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When moving folders around, you should change the python path in your `vscode/.settings` file. Otherwise you'll be using the wrong Python interpreter - one without Flask.